# Saving to properties file escapes :

Tags: java, properties

Does anyone know why the colons are getting escaped when I store the properties file?

I'm doing this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();


// Set the properties value.

prop.setProperty("url","http://localhost:7101/test/home");
```

And storing using:

```
prop.store(new FileOutputStream(propFile), null);
```

It's working but the output has colons escaped for some reason:

```
url=http\://localhost\:7101/test/home
```

Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In properties files, both of these are legit:

```
key1 = value
key2: value
```

So both = and : must be escaped.

Now, if you read the thing back with Properties, it's no problem. Otherwise, you'll have to write custom code

Comment: Beat me to it. Teaches me right for first writing test code rather than going for the Javadoc.

Comment: Respect to writing test code! (makes you wonder why people asking the question don't start off doing that ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's what the [store()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) API does:-

> Each character of the key and element
>   strings is examined to see whether it
>   should be rendered as an escape
>   sequence. The ASCII characters \, tab,
>   form feed, newline, and carriage
>   return are written as \, \t, \f \n,
>   and \r, respectively. Characters less
>   than \u0020 and characters greater
>   than \u007E are written as \uxxxx for
>   the appropriate hexadecimal value
>   xxxx. For the key, all space
>   characters are written with a
>   preceding \ character. For the
>   element, leading space characters, but
>   not embedded or trailing space
>   characters, are written with a
>   preceding \ character. The key and
>   element characters #, !, =, and : are
>   written with a preceding backslash to
>   ensure that they are properly loaded.

It shouldn't really matter to you as long as you use `Properties` to get the values.